# How do I insert at a specific position in a Doc? (Inside a text item?)

Tags: google-apps-script

My goal is to find the position of some text in a document, delete that text, and put something else its place. I thought I would start by just inserting the new text first, but it doesn't go anywhere near where I thought it would.

The relevant lines of code are here:

```
matchPosition = theDoc.getBody().findText("put stuff here").getStartOffset();

theDoc.getBody().insertParagraph(matchPosition, "The new stuff");
```

"put stuff here" is in the middle of a document with all sort of other text and formatting.

I'm guessing this can't be done the way I think it can. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The function you tried using, `insertParagraph` takes an index as parameter, which is the index of the *paragraph*, not the place when the text will go.

Instead of appending the text then removing what was there, you could simply replace it

```
theDoc.getBody().replaceText("put stuff here", "The new stuff");
```

Or, if you want to place text at a precise position, you could use the function `editAsText` of the body, and then `insertText`

```
matchPosition = theDoc.getBody().findText("put stuff here").getStartOffset();
theDoc.getBody().editAsText().insertText(matchPosition, "The new stuff");
```

If you want more info, you should check out the complete list of function of the class body [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body)

Comment: I tried to distill my problem so as not to overcomplicate things for the answerer, but I see now I may have made it more complicated. I'm using insert paragraph and other insert methods because I need to preserve the formatting of things (which I'm "copying" from other Google docs). If I operate on things "as text" then I lose my formatting. I will dig into the "index" documentation some more, as I don't quite understand that and I'm sure I should...

Comment: @Liora Haydont I tried your matctPosition statement. It does not put text at the specified position. Rather it places the text at the start. For example, if the value of       
 matctPosition = 0, then it places new text at the start of a document rather than at start of this line. Hope you got this.