# Can I copy the contents of one doc to a specific spot in another doc? (Google Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a document which says "Paste STUFF here" and I want to paste (insert, append, whatever it takes) the contents of another document into that very spot, preserving the formatting from the original document.

I modified some canonical code to do the copying, which I'm pasting in here in case it helps.

I'm at a point where I'm thinking I may need to split up the original document and then just use my code to create a document consisting of

PART 1 of ORIGINAL
STUFF
PART 2 of ORIGINAL

This is rather ugly, so I hope someone knows a better way!

```
 function copyFromTo(fromDocID,toDocID) {
  var toDoc = DocumentApp.openById(toDocID);
  var body = toDoc.getBody();


    var fromDocBody = DocumentApp.openById(fromDocID).getBody(); 
    Logger.log(fromDocBody.getAttributes());
    var totalElements = fromDocBody.getNumChildren();
    var latestElement;
    for( var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j ) {
      var element = fromDocBody.getChild(j).copy();
      var attributes = fromDocBody.getChild(j).getAttributes();
      // Log attributes for comparison
      Logger.log(attributes);
      Logger.log(element.getAttributes());
      var type = element.getType(); 
      if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
        if (element.asParagraph().getNumChildren() != 0 && element.asParagraph().getChild(0).getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE) {
          var pictattr = element.asParagraph().getChild(0).asInlineImage().getAttributes();
          var blob = element.asParagraph().getChild(0).asInlineImage().getBlob();
          // Image attributes, e.g. size, do not survive the copy, and need to be applied separately
          latestElement = body.appendImage(blob);
          latestElement.setAttributes(clean(pictattr));
        }
        else latestElement = body.appendParagraph(element);
      }
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE )
        latestElement = body.appendTable(element);
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM )
        latestElement = body.appendListItem(element);
      else
        throw new Error("Unsupported element type: "+type);
      // If you find that element attributes are not coming through, uncomment the following
      // line to explicitly copy the element attributes from the original doc.
      //latestElement.setAttributes(clean(attributes));
    }
  }



/**
 * Remove null attributes in style object, obtained by call to
 * .getAttributes().
 * https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2899
 */
function clean(style) {
  for (var attr in style) {
    if (style[attr] == null) delete style[attr];
  }
  return style;
}
```

Comment: Well? Did you have a specific question on your implementation? If you don't see a relevant API method when you study the Google Docs API reference on the Apps Script documentation website (Help -> Documentation), then you have to either A) use existing methods to create your desired functionality, or B) change your approach. It's not clear what you've done at all.

Comment: I just included my code to show people how I'm currently copying from one doc to another, My question is in the headline:

Can I copy the contents of one doc to a specific spot in another doc?

To which I should add... preserving formatting.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216897/how-do-i-insert-at-a-specific-position-in-a-doc-inside-a-text-item)?

Comment: Yes. I asked that question, and I'm unable to use the answer because I need to preserve formatting when I insert stuff in the specific location.

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you'll need to iterate over every paragraph of the "toDoc" until you find the one if the desired text. Then you find out which element is the parent (it could be the body or a table) and the relative index of the paragraph to be replaced.

```
/*This function receives the paragraph element that will replace the 
  placeholder text 'Paste STUFF here' and uses the current ActiveDocument as the destination*/
function copyIntoPaceholder(copiedParagraph) {
  var toDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = toDoc.getBody();
  var paragraphs = body.getParagraphs();
  var paragraph;
  for(var p = 0; p <paragraphs.length; p++) { //iterate over every paragraph
    paragraph = paragraphs[p];
    if(paragraph.getText() === "Paste STUFF here") { //finds the text to be replaced
      var container = paragraph.getParent(); //finds the parent of the paragraph to be replaced
      var paragraphIndex = container.getChildIndex(paragraph) //gets the index of the paragraph to be replaced in its parent.
      paragraph.removeFromParent() //deletes the placeholder paragraph from the document
      container.insertParagraph(paragraphIndex, copiedParagraph) //insert the new paragraph at the desired location
      break
    }
  }
}
```